# Is there a way to cancel TabControl.Items.CurrentChanging?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem, selectionchanging

There is unfortunately no TabControl.SelectionChanging event (Selector.SelectionChanging), I am struggling to implement this behavior so I can cancel the changing request.

I tried to handle the `TabControl.Items.CurrentChanging` (the `Items` property is and `ItemCollection`) event setting e.Cancel (of the `CurrentChangingEventArgs`) to true, but the UI is is updated with the new tab although the item is not changed in the collection.

Is there any way to prevent user from switching to a different `TabItem` when a condition is dissatisfied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason why this happens, and it annoys me greatly.

But here's my workaround for it:

In the sample below, checkbox is "locking" the current tab. So checked means user can't change tab.

```
void Items_CurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        var item = ((ICollectionView)sender).CurrentItem;

        e.Cancel = true;

        tabControl1.SelectedItem = item;
    }
}
```

Basically, what happens is (if I understand this correctly) the visual tree gets updated, but the logical tree does not. The above way forces the visual to sync with the logical tree.

Comment: A note: I had to also manually set the new tab if I did not cancel the event. No idea why, but otherwise the tab wouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can also handle the [PreviewLostKeyboardFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewlostkeyboardfocus.aspx) event on each [TabItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem.aspx), and set the [Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx) property of the event arguments to `true` to prevent switching to another tab:

```
protected void tabItem_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender,
    KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidateTabItem((TabItem) sender)) {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

See http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/how-to-cancel-navigation-between-tabitems-in-a-tabcontrol-84994.shtml.