# WPF Cancelling Tab Selection causes Changing event to happen twice

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, selectionchanging

I am doing something like the following to prevent a tab selection from changing:

```
 tabControl.Items.CurrentChanging += new CurrentChangingEventHandler(Items_CurrentChanging);

 void Items_CurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
 {
     if( dataIsInvalid )
     {
          // Show some popup message
          var item = ((ICollectionView)sender).CurrentItem;
          e.Cancel = true;
          tabControl.SelectedItem = item; // !! This causes the CurrentChanging event to happen twice !! 
                                          // But without this the visual tree does not update! :( 
     }
}
```

However the problem that I am seeing right now is that the last line above causes a CurrentChanging event to happen a second time, and my popup message is displayed twice. Not only that, it is displayed the second time after bringing another window into focus first, and then putting focus back on my tab control's window.
Any ideas why this could be happening?

--EDIT--
It looks like I should really only need `e.Cancel` and not require updating the `SelectedItem` again. However the visual tree is not updated unless I do this. Is there any way I can ensure the visual tree of the tab control is updated after `e.Cancel` occurs, without having to update the `SelectedItem`?

Comment: Doesn't only `e.Cancel=true;` work?

Comment: I agree with LPL on the e.Cancel.  Personally I don't like popups.  Another approach is to validate the input and display the validation error via validation.  And you could even disable all other tabs on a validation error.

Comment: unfortunately just using `e.Cancel` doesn't work, the tab selection still changes :s  It looks like this person had a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194290/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-tabcontrol-items-currentchanging but the workaround causes strange behavior for me, as I described above.

Comment: Also, I agree that the popup is not ideal, but this is also where the user is asked whether they want to save their changes.

Comment: are you by any chance using the "loaded" event in your usercontrol?

Comment: nope I have not used the `Loaded` event (other than printing statements for debugging).

Comment: You could still use the popup and disable the the other tabs when data in invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a little wierd... you can deterministically unhook and hook the current changing event handler in the `PreviewMouseDown` on tab control.

And in CurrentChanging itself unhook the handler so this way it will not be called multiple times atleast.

```
    private void MyTabControl_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabControl = sender as TabControl;

        if (tabControl != null)
        {
            var temp = new CurrentChangingEventHandler((sender1, e1) => { });
            var handler = new CurrentChangingEventHandler(
                (sender1, e1) =>
                    {
                        var item = ((ICollectionView) sender1).CurrentItem;
                        if (item != null && dataIsInvalid)
                        {
                            e1.Cancel = true;
                            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                                new Action(() =>
                                   {
                                       tabControl.SelectedItem = item;
                                   }));
                        }

                        tabControl.Items.CurrentChanging -= temp;
                    });

            temp = handler;
            tabControl.Items.CurrentChanging -= handler;
            tabControl.Items.CurrentChanging += handler;
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I just ran into this problem now with a tab control. All I did was unhoook the handler before I called it.

```
InsturmentTabs.Items.CurrentChanging -= new CurrentChangingEventHandler(Items_CurrentChanging);
InsturmentTabs.Items.CurrentChanging += new CurrentChangingEventHandler(Items_CurrentChanging);

private void Items_CurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            var item = ((ICollectionView)sender).CurrentItem;
            e.Cancel = true;

            InsturmentTabs.SelectedItem = item;              
        }                                          
    }
```