# WPF Validate/Setter calls in wrong order

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a textbox inside a TabControl. The textbox binding has UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus. The textbox uses Attribute based validation from the data model. This validation is working correctly.

In the TabControl.SelectedItemChanged event I call modelObject.Validate() and prevent the switch to a different tab if an error occurs.
The problem I have is that the order of execution is backwards. The validate call occurs before the property setter. In the case of an invalid field I am able to switch away from the tab even though an error has been detected.

How do I get the order or these events ordered properly?

Answer (score 0):

[Is there a way to cancel TabControl.Items.CurrentChanging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194290/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-tabcontrol-items-currentchanging/4194548#4194548)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8ac2677-b760-4388-a797-b39db84a7e0f/how-to-cancel-tabcontrolselectionchanged?forum=wpf

Seems to work by subscribing the CurrentChanging event. Can cancel tab changing action by setting the CurrentChangingEventArgs Cancel to true

Comment: This is not my question -- I know how to cancel the selection changed event.  I want to know how I get WPF to order the textbox.lostfocus and tabcontrol.Selectionchanged events in the correct order. i.e. lostfocus then Selectionchanged -- not the other way round.

Comment: The CurrentChanging event happened before the SelectionChanged event. You can do whatever you want at the handler e.g. Switching the focus to whatever control other than the textbox if u like. But the thing is ... When I look at ur problem ... Isn't the "validation" of the textbox u wanna perform? Whether the validation execution came from LostFocus or not isn't really is the key, rite?

Answer (score 0):

WPF is definitely incorrect here. However, the fix is really simple.
In the SelectionChanged event handler call {whatever your tabcontrol is called}.Focus(). This immediately forces the lostfocus event for the textbox (which forces the setter to be fired) and solves the problem.